# Error: "Cannot send session cache limiter" related to encoding

Tags: php, session, http-headers

I'm started having problems with the encoding, it seems that somehow Notepad++ changed the encoding or something. Anyway all files where encoded in UTF-8, but I checked and some changed to UTF-8 without BOM. Changing one to UTF-8 fixed the special characters issue.

`"TageÃƒÂ¡"` changed to `"Tageá"` but I started getting an error:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/02/6945202/html/usuario/index.php:1) in /home/content/02/6945202/html/usuario/index.php on line 1
```

This is line 1:

```
<? session_start(); ?>
```

I don't understand why I'm having this issue, since using ANSI or UTF-8 without BOM the page shows with no errors.

What can be the problem? Thanks

Comment: It's because php sends the utf encoding characters at the start which identify UTF8.

Comment: Use the correct content-type `charset=` parameter (webserver or php.ini) instead of the UTF-8 BOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blog.onitindustries.com/php/errors/php-session_start-on-first-line-still-getting-error/

ok try using this function to convert strings, save file as utf-8 without bom for this.

```
<?php
session_start();
function charset_decode_utf_8 ($string) {
  /* Only do the slow convert if there are 8-bit characters */
    /* avoid using 0xA0 (\240) in ereg ranges. RH73 does not like that */
    if (! ereg("[\200-\237]", $string) and ! ereg("[\241-\377]", $string))
        return $string;

    // decode three byte unicode characters
    $string = preg_replace("/([\340-\357])([\200-\277])([\200-\277])/e",     
    "'&#'.((ord('\\1')-224)*4096 + (ord('\\2')-128)*64 + (ord('\\3')-128)).';'",    
    $string);

    // decode two byte unicode characters
    $string = preg_replace("/([\300-\337])([\200-\277])/e", 
    "'&#'.((ord('\\1')-192)*64+(ord('\\2')-128)).';'", 
    $string);

    return $string;
}
echo charset_decode_utf_8('TageÃƒÂ¡');
?>
```

Comment: It's probably that, however when I save without BOM I get a lot of random extra characters across the site.
http://chusmix.com/top/?ciudad=Pilar

Maybe it's a problem with Notepad++

Comment: can you save as utf-8 without bom then do what i put in the updated answer?... hmmm scratch that idea. It removes ƒ from the string.

Answer (score 0):

This is generally caused by having some output before you make the above call.  This happens because output must come after headers, so if there is output the headers are sent.  Whitespace will cause this to happen, which can even be caused by spaces or newlines before or after the PHP tags.

To fix this problem you can eliminate all output before this call, though this is often not feasible.

A better solution is to enable output_buffering in your php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

convert character encoding without changing the file encoding to UTF-8 without BOM because it is generating space before session_start()